# How to add a menu item to Excel 2010 Cell Context Menu - old code doesn't work

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, contextmenu

I've tried 3 different code samples and they all fail.

Here's the code from a MSFT employee ([How to show a context menu on a range](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/exceldev/thread/b4e953a1-e733-49eb-90fc-87e7d16e9dd4?prof=required)), the other two samples have pretty much the exact same code:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    CommandBar cellbar = this.Application.CommandBars["Cell"];
    CommandBarButton button = (CommandBarButton) cellbar.FindControl(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, 0, "MYRIGHTCLICKMENU", Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
    if (button == null)
    {
        // add the button
        button = (CommandBarButton) cellbar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, cellbar.Controls.Count, true);
        button.Caption = "Refresh";
        button.BeginGroup = true;
        button.Tag = "MYRIGHTCLICKMENU";
        button.Click += new _CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(MyButton_Click);
    }
}

private void MyButton_Click(CommandBarButton cmdBarbutton, ref bool cancel)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("MyButton was Clicked", "MyCOMAddin");
}
```

**I'm expecting to see a menu item called Refresh when right clicking on a cell. Yet running the above code (in Excel 2010) there is no 'Refresh' menu item.**

What might I be missing, or did this functionality change from 2007 to 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check to see if this type of code exists (either in your own addin or any other addin's your company uses) and if it does either comment it out or move it to the _Shutdown event of the addin.

```
//reset commandbars
Application.CommandBars["Cell"].Reset();
```

Comment: Thanks, another add-in was loading and had this reset code that was deleting my menu item

Answer (score 0):

Too late for the question but may help others... Below code works fine for me.

```
private void OnSheetRightClick(object Sh, Excel.Range Target, ref bool Cancel)
{
    // code to create the menu item button
}


private void InternalStartup()
{
    this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
    this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
    this.Application.SheetBeforeRightClick += OnSheetRightClick;
}
```