# Excel button event doesn't fire when spreadsheet is re-opened

Tags: c#, excel, event-handling, vsto

When I add a button or link to a spreadsheet the click event works. However when I save the spreadsheet, close it and reopen it the event doesn't fire.

```
AddControl(xlApp, ((TaskPaneView)this.Parent).factory, "text", "A1");

public void AddControl(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp, Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.ApplicationFactory factory, string controlText, string address)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet nativeWorksheet = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet;
    Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet vstoWorksheet = factory.GetVstoObject(nativeWorksheet);
    var btn = new Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Controls.Button();
    btn.Name = "link1";
    btn.Text = controlText;
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_Click);
    vstoWorksheet.Controls.AddControl(btn, nativeWorksheet.Range[address], controlText);
}

void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

**Is there a easy way to hook up the event again when the WorkBook is opened?**

*I'm thinking I will have to search the workbook for the buttons and AddHandler's manually.*

**Edit:** This is documented but there is no mention of the problem after closing the spreadsheet: [Adding Controls to a Worksheet at Run Time in an Application-Level Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442817.aspx)

Comment: Is this an add-in or workbook project? With an add-in, I don't think you can do what you want, the control and code doesn't get saved with the workbook.

Comment: Its a VSTO Add-In... I'll elaborate in answer.

Comment: You may be better off working with a Workbook project, then. From what you are describing, what you need is really a custom workbook. Conceptually, an add-in is an extension to Excel itself, and typically you are adding functionality to the application, not to a specific workbook.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion I'll look into that approach. The Excel Add-In is a CubeBrowser (like in SSAS 2005 and 2008) and the buttons were to bring up the Add-In with the MDX query loaded. I figure a context menu will do the trick. Your assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: One other approach is to put your button in a Task Pane, with all the functionality you want from your app. That way, you can trigger it any time, and generate a workbook on the fly to display your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[When a document is saved and then closed, all dynamic host controls are removed from the document. Only the underlying native Office objects remain behind.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442765(v=vs.100).aspx).

---

I might do it another way now, create VBA buttons with code to tap into the [Add-In functionality](http://vbadud.blogspot.com.au/2008/11/call-method-in-vsto-addin-from-visual.html):

VBA code:

```
Dim oAddin As COMAddIn
Dim oCOMFuncs As Object
Set oAddin = Application.COMAddIns(ExcelAddInNameSpace")
Set oCOMFuncs = oAddin.Object
oCOMFuncs.CallAFunctionOfAddIn
```

---

Or another way using context menu's (when over NamedRanges).

---

More info from [MSFT](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/59d32994-91bc-49a8-90b1-8dd46e8997ce):

> But here comes the problem: if you save the workbook, open it on
>   either a machine with the add-in intalled or a clean machine, the
>   button doesn't work this time!
>
> So we can see that adding controls onto document's surface via add-in
>   doesn't make a lot of sense as the controls may loss its
>   functionality. This is why we generally suggest to use Custom Task
>   Pane instead of adding controls onto surface of document. Have a look
>   at following documents:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338197(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: @HeinrichStack I'm pretty sure I ended up doing it with Context Menu, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528775/how-to-add-a-menu-item-to-excel-2010-cell-context-menu-old-code-doesnt-work)