# VSIX Commands not showing in Release Version

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsix

I've created an extension for VS 2017. When I launch the debug instance, it is working fine. If I build the VSIX, install it, the commands do not show up on the Tools menu. The extension is showing up as installed. I added some code to display a message box when the commands are created, the message boxes show up.

Multiple uninstalls and reinstalls do not work.

Update: I created a new VSIX project and imported my solution into the new project and now it's working.

Comment: Another developer at your company isn't resetting menus after their use? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10529411/495455. You might want to share how you're doing it, are you using envDTE2 to add the menus? A [mcve] would be ideal. Good luck! Also  menus are hidden with the wrong Environment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604119/visual-studio-test-missing-from-the-main-menu

Comment: Can you share some code? Or some log-messages from inside VS? Are you using signing for your extension